# hibernate core,Hibernate annotations or hibernate entity manager

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm working on a project an i have to decide witch of these technologies fits better. could anyone explain the main differences between hibernate core, Hibernate annotations and hibernate entity manager (the advantages of each on detriment of the others) generally .. Hibernate vs JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

HibernateCore - as name says, the core for everything - entity mapping via xml files

Hibernate annotations - Aditional component that allows you to map your entities annotated classes with annotated fields etc.

EntityManager - Hibernate's implementation of JPA2 standard.

I personally use Hibernate core with annotatios, however every new project i will be participating in, I will desing in such way to use JPA2 with Hibernate.

Comment: thank you for your response , in fact i know the definition of each one .. but what i want to know is the advantages and why should I use one technology better then the other .. i have read somthing about portability of code and other things ..

Comment: If you stick to JPA you will be able to switch between implementations without touching your code. I think that is the most important advantage (and I cannot point anything else really). It is standarized and therefore should be more flexible, functional and has less bugs (IMHO)